# "Es regnet" – worauf bezieht sich das "es"?

Tags: grammar

Normalerweise lässt sich in den meisten Sätzen ja ein Personalpronomen durch die handelnde Person ersetzen, "er rennt" -> "Thomas rennt" z.B.

Aber wenn wir sagen "es regnet", wer regnet dann? Das Wetter? "Das Wetter regnet" klingt irgendwie falsch. Wie ist dieser Ausdruck entstanden? Kanns sein, dass das (weils auch im Französischen und Englischem so ist) eine Personalisierung ist? Das Wetter als "Naturgott" oder sowas in der Art, was sich dann langsam aber in das "es" (il, it) umgewandelt hat, weil man diese Götter vergessen hat?

Oder denke ich dabei zu kompliziert und es gibt eine ganz einfache Erklärung?

Comment: Vergessene Götter … da muss ich direkt and das gleichnamige Lied von Saltatio Mortis denken, das ungefähr in diese Kerbe schlägt ;)

Comment: Die gleiche Frage kann man auch für anderen Sprachen stellen. Im Englischen heisst es z.B.: "It is raining."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zu deiner Vermutung: Geben (*es gibt*) und weitere Verben setzen keinen Gott voraus. Also, nein würde ich erstmal  sagen. Im literarischen Sinne kann auch *Blut* und was auch immer regnen. Gäbe es ein stillschweigendes Subjekt da, so würde man denken, das Subjekt ist schlicht *Wasser*. Und weil *regnet Wasser* nach Wiederholung klingt, wird dies unterdrückt.

Zur Grammatik: Da versteht man *es* als [formales Subjekt](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-es.html)

> **es** *als formales Subjekt bei unpersönlichen Verben*: 
>   Das Pronomen es steht als rein formales, d. h. bedeutungsloses Subjekt bei unpersönlichen und unpersönlich verwendeten Verben. Es kann in der Regel nicht weggelassen oder ersetzt werden.