# What is the function of the ‘es’ in this sentence?

Tags: pronoun, expletiva

> Es sind nicht alle gleich.

I understand this sentence to mean, “Not everyone’s the same”, but what is the *es* in aid of?

Would the following have the same meaning?

> Alle sind nicht gleich.

[The linked duplicate question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/es-regnet-worauf-bezieht-sich-das-es) does not help me as the *es* in that is raining, but the *es* in my sentence doesn’t seem to have a verb or anything attached to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Es regnet" – worauf bezieht sich das "es"?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/es-regnet-worauf-bezieht-sich-das-es)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is a different grammatical phenomenon. Compare ‘Heute regnet *es*’ and ‘heute sind alle gleich’.

Comment: Only the _es_ in "Es sind nicht alle gleich." can be replaced by a locative adverb: "Da/Hier/Dort/In Berlin sind nicht alle gleich."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have stumbled across the use of *es* as a syntactical expletive.

German sentences (main clauses only; within the context of this answer unless otherwise mentioned) are split into three parts by their included verbs: the *Vorfeld* (preceeding a finite verb in second position), the *Hauptfeld* (between a finite verb in second position and infinitives or participles at the end) and the *Nachfeld* (anything following the last set of verbs). Consider this example:

> Ich   **bin**   heute in die Stadt   **gegangen**   um einzukaufen.

The verbs responsible are bolded. The *Vorfeld* is occupied by *ich*, the *Hauptfeld* by *heute in die Stadt* and the *Nachfeld* by *um einzukaufen.*

Most German sentences will not have anything in the *Nachfeld*. However, almost all German sentence **must** include something in the *Vorfeld.* This is typically associated with the subject of a sentence or with something that requires emphasis. An empty *Vorfeld* will mark one of a very small class of phrases:

- Imperatives; the verb must be first in these

  > **Geh** in die Stadt um einzukaufen!
- Unmarked conditional clauses allow for a special construction:

  > **Gehe** ich in die Stadt, kaufe ich wahrscheinlich ein.

  Which can be rewritten using a conditional subordinate clause in the following way:

  > Wenn ich in die Stadt **gehe,** kaufe ich wahrscheinlich ein.

  (Note that the second main clause, *kaufe ich wahrscheinlich ein* has the first clause occupying its *Vorfeld.)*

Now sometimes, Germans don’t want to add emphasis to anything within a sencence and sometimes a sentence just naturally comes without a subject.<sup>[1]</sup> If that is the case and there is nothing to fill the *Vorfeld,* the sentence could be mistaken for a conditional clause. To prevent that, a *syntactical expletive* is added which merely fulfils the role of keeping the *Vorfeld* occupied in the absence of other candidates.

> **Es** sind nicht alle gleich.
>
> **Es** wird gefeiert.

(This second one is special, because aside from placing the past participle *gefeiert* into the *Vorfeld* there is nothing else that can go there; and ‘Gefeiert wird’ is not considered valid across all of Germany.)

In your case, the usage of the expletive is only due to reduce emphasis. There is nothing wrong with a sentence like:

> Nicht alle sind gleich.
>
> Gleich sind nicht alle.

Where the expletive disappears. Note that *nicht alle* is the sentence’s subject and hence the verb displays plural number.

---

A final note on your proposed alternative: the *nicht* is used to negate the *alle* in your example sentence. Thus, it must stay closely connected to *alle.* Putting them *both* into the *Vorfeld* is fine but separating them is not.

Answer (score 1):

> Alle sind nicht gleich.

The word order would be wrong. In this word order the sentence would mean that every single person is "not equal". However when speaking about single persons what does "equal" mean?

To say that it is not the case that all persons are equal the following word order is correct:

> Nicht alle sind gleich.

User *guidot* posted a link about the word "*es*" in the following sentence:

> *Es* regnet.

The situation here is different because in this case the word "*es*" cannot be left out while in the case of "*Es sind nicht alle gleich*" it is possible to write the sentence without the "*es*".

In the case of "*Es regnet.*" or in English "*It rains.*" you can see that the word "*es*" or "*it*" is used if a sentence does not give any information **who** is doing something but only about the fact that something is happening: **Who** is raining?

I don't know an official rule but **my personal feeling** as a native speaker is that the form using the "*es*" is used in some cases to express that the essential information is somehow different.

Example:

> Drei Kinder sind heute zur Schule gegangen.

The information **I** would extract from this sentence is: **What** did the three kids do today? (Answer: They went to school.)

> Es sind heute drei Kinder zur Schule gegangen.

The information **I** would extract from this sentence is: **How many** kids went to school today? (Answer: Three.)

Asking a teacher about the number of kids that came to school today he'll probably use the form using the "*es*".

Just like in the sentence "*Es regnet.*" valid sentences seem never to contain (exact) information about **who** is doing something - at least in "modern" German language. You will typically never see sentences like:

> Es gehe **ich** zur Schule.
>
> Es gehst **du** zur Schule.
>
> Es geht **Max Müller** zur Schule.

... in modern language. Sentences which are similar to the third example can sometimes be found in literature or old German.

Comment: "Es gehe ich zur Schule"? Really? Can you post a link to that, please? Or just to any example of a similar construction?

Comment: @TonyK As I already wrote: "I never heard something like this in modern language". The first part of the sentence (old German / literature) applies to the third example (Max Müller), not to the first one (ich). I was just looking for an example in Google: There seems to be a children game named "*Es geht der schlaue Fuchs herum.*". Normally you would say: "*Der schlaue Fuchs geht...*".

Comment: Yes, and "Es geht der schlaue Fuchs herum" is a construction that you usually find in poetry. However, this kind of construction pretty much always requires a verb that has been flexed to reflect tense, the infinitive is not appropriate here; furthermore, it does not work with these pronouns, I never heard this used other than with the third person singular or plural.

Comment: Another example: *Es tanzt ein Bi-Ba-Butzemann*

Comment: But Martin, you say "the following sentences can sometimes be found". It seems that this is simply false for your first- and second-person examples ("ich" and "du"). If so, can you please edit your post?

Comment: @Iris: I already saw this example but to me this seems more like "*Es gehen drei Kinder zur Schule*" because the sentence names "***ein** Bi-Ba-Butzemann*" and not "***der** Bi-Ba-Butzemann*".

Comment: @TonyK Sorry. I should have written "**Sentences like these**" and not "**The following sentences**". That was wrong. I'll edit my post at once.

Comment: @Martin Rosenau, I don't understand the difference....

Comment: My point is that this construction has _never_ been used with a first- or second-person verb. So your first two example sentences are impossible, in old or new German. I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @Iris From the grammar there is no difference. But I have written that such a construction is typically not used when the subject is exactly defined. "***Der** schlaue Fuchs*" exactly defines one animal while "***ein** Bi-Ba-Butzemann*" would imply that there are more "*Bi-Ba-Butzemänner*" and the sentence is not exactly defining which of them is meant.

Comment: @TonyK I cannot find an example for this. But I think I have already read some poems where this construction has been used with "*du*" and with "*wir*". Especially in song texts where the exact number of syllables is important.

Comment: @MartinRosenau, ah. Now, I got it.